# can't seem to connect to a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, networking, minikube

I have the following service/deployment where I the docker image just responds to requests on port 80 with "hello world"

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: helloworld
          image: */helloworld:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "250m"
              memory: "1Gi"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.0.10
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I'm expecting to be able to connect to 192.168.0.10:80, but I get "took too long to respond"

I can verify the service is running with `minikube kubectl get services` which gives me

`test         LoadBalancer   10.97.157.242    192.168.0.10   80:31912/TCP     48m`

and the pod the service points to is started. `minikube kubectl get pods` gives me

`test-55c8cc69b5-h7xj6       1/1     Running       0             11s`

Comment: I don't think setting a Service's `externalIPs:` field actually does anything.  Does [Kubernetes (Minikube) external ip does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850819/kubernetes-minikube-external-ip-does-not-work) describe your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access):

> Services of type `LoadBalancer` can be exposed via the `minikube tunnel`
> command. It must be run in a separate terminal window to keep the
> `LoadBalancer` running.

Running `minikube tunnel` in a separate terminal should make your Service accessible.